# kotest equivalent to usingElementComparatorIgnoringFields from assertJ

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, frameworks, assertj, kotest

assertJ allows you to check for element-wise list equality while ignoring user specified fields like so

```
assertThat(listOfObjects)
    .usingElementComparatorIgnoringFields("field1", "field2", ...)
    .containsExactly(object1, object2, ...)
```

I have not been able to find any equivalent function in kotest. Is there an equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such assertion at collection level, though you can perform similar assertion at individual object using `shouldBeEqualToIgnoringFields` matcher.

https://github.com/kotest/kotest/blob/1f4069d78faead65a0d7e8c7f1b689b417a655d2/kotest-assertions/kotest-assertions-core/src/jvmMain/kotlin/io/kotest/matchers/equality/reflection.kt#L127

https://kotest.io/docs/assertions/core-matchers.html

Answer (score 0):

In Kotest version 5.6.0, this feature has been implemented:

```
collection.shouldContainAllIgnoringFields(other, fields...)
```

Advertised: https://kotest.io/docs/assertions/collection-matchers.html but with no help on how to use, so you might find this source code test useful:

https://github.com/kotest/kotest/commit/923128c5c0a02f8af0198f03a2f429559d50d410